# Dnsmasq not resolving hosts that have static IP

Tags: linux, dnsmasq

I am wanting to keep all of my configuration in the dnsmasq.conf file, therefore, am not maintaining a separate hosts file.

For some machines that are not running a DHCP client, and never request an IP lease, those machines will not be returned when dnsmasq is asked for name resolution.

In this example, "proxy" has a static IP, and "mediapi" is a DHCP client.

```
root at routerpi:/etc# nslookup proxy
Server:        127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find proxy: No answer

root at routerpi:/etc# nslookup mediapi
Server:        127.0.0.1
Address:    127.0.0.1#53

Name:    mediapi
Address: 192.168.10.203
```

The entries in dnsmasq look like this:

```
dhcp-host=192.168.10.203,mediapi
dhcp-host=192.168.10.61,proxy
```

I have also tried the format that includes MAC addresses, but the result
is the same:

```
dhcp-host=dc:a6:32:4f:ce:4e,192.168.10.203,mediapi
```

And the log file contains:

```
dnsmasq: 147 127.0.0.1/53500 query[A] mediapi from 127.0.0.1
dnsmasq: 147 127.0.0.1/53500 DHCP mediapi is 192.168.10.203

dnsmasq: 171 127.0.0.1/56905 query[A] proxy from 127.0.0.1
dnsmasq: 171 127.0.0.1/56905 config proxy is NODATA-IPv4
```

How do I get the static IP hosts to be resolved?

This used to work, and I'm not sure what's changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `host-record` option to define names that aren't associated with DHCP.

```
host-record = proxy, 192.168.10.61
```